# Why getElementById returns null when called inside a Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a class like below and I want to pass an element for further customization. The class should be responsible of setting up the size of the box and adds elements to it. I having hard time applying the necessary styles needed to element.

```
class BoxBuilder {
    constructor(element, items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.elm   = document.getElementById(element);
    }
    setSize(h, w) {
        console.log(this.elm); // returns null
        this.elm.style.width = w;
        this.elm.style.height = h;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And with jQuery :

```
class BoxBuilder {
    constructor(element, items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.elm   = $(element);
    }
    setSize(h, w) {
        console.log(this.elm); // returns [context: document, selector: "#box-container"]
        this.elm.style.width = w;
        this.elm.style.height = h;
        return this;
    }
}


// here is what I am trying to achieve
var box = new BoxBuilder('#box-container').setSize(300, 250);
```

Comment: Did you call `new BoxBuilder(...)` *after* the DOM was loaded?

Comment: How do you call it for the first one? Do you include the "#" like you do with jQuery? If you do, there is your problem...

Comment: Thanks... my problem was calling it before the dom ready :) cheers

Comment: @RocketHazmat where is more appropriate to handle the dom ready event, outside of the class or inside?

Comment: I'd put it outside the class.  I think it's cleaner that way.

Comment: nevermind. outside :)

Comment: right, that is what i thought

Answer (score 3):

You're using a CSS selector where it's not supposed to be used. jQuery takes CSS selectors such as `#box-container` then strips off the `#` because that indicates it's an ID. To use `document.getElementById` just avoid using `#`.

So rewrite your assignment line as:

```
var box = new BoxBuilder('box-container').setSize(300, 250);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use straight JavaScript, you are getting null because you don't use the `#` as a part of the ID. That is an identifier for jQuery that you are looking for an element with that ID. The alternative is `.`, which would be by class. (Other CSS style selectors are also valid.)

So what you want to send when only using JavaScript is `var box = new BoxBuilder('box-container').setSize(300, 250);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are calling `document.getElementById` *after* the DOM is loaded.  Otherwise, you won't find anything.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var box = new BoxBuilder('box-container').setSize(300, 250);
});
```